# Twitter : weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable: Cannot handle string attributes

Tags: twitter, weka, naivebayes

I've started my work on weka few days back. (i.e.i'm new to weka and java too)

I'm finding the evaluation measures using weka for tweets. I'm getting following error while running the program :

weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable: Cannot handle string attributes!
weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable: Cannot handle string attributes!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Unknown Source)
    at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable.buildClassifier(Unknown Source)
    at com.ConnectGlobe.TextDirectoryToArff.main(TextDirectoryToArff.java:83)

**Program:**

```
package com.ConnectGlobe;
import java.io.*;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable;
import weka.core.*;
/**
 *
 * @author sv
 */
public class TextDirectoryToArff {

  public Instances createDataset(String directoryPath) throws Exception {

    FastVector atts = new FastVector(2);
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("filename", (FastVector) null));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
    Instances data = new Instances("text_files_in_" + directoryPath, atts, 0);

    File dir = new File(directoryPath);
    String[] files = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith(".txt")) {
    try {
      double[] newInst = new double[2];
      newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(files[i]);
      File txt = new File(directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
      InputStreamReader is;
      is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txt));
      StringBuffer txtStr = new StringBuffer();
      int c;
      while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        txtStr.append((char)c);
      }
      newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
      data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //System.err.println("failed to convert file: " + directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
    }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     TextDirectoryToArff tdta1 = new TextDirectoryToArff();
     TextDirectoryToArff tdta2 = new TextDirectoryToArff();
      try {
    Instances dataset1 = tdta1.createDataset("C:\\1"); // .txt file will be loaded
    dataset1.setClassIndex(dataset1.numAttributes() - 1 );
    Instances dataset2 = tdta2.createDataset("C:\\2");
    dataset2.setClassIndex(dataset1.numAttributes() - 1);

    System.out.println(dataset1);
    System.out.println(dataset2);

    double precision = 0, recall=0,fmeasure=0,error=0;

    int size1 = dataset1.numInstances() / 10;
    int size2 = dataset2.numInstances() / 10;

    int begin = 0;
    int end = size1 - 1 ;

    for (int i=1 ; i<=10;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("iteration :" + 1);

        Instances training = new Instances(dataset1);
        Instances testing = new Instances(dataset1, begin , (end - begin));

        for (int j=0;j < (end - begin); j++)
            training.delete(begin);

        Classifier tree = (Classifier)new NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable();


    Instances filteredInstaces = training;
    StringToNominal nominal ;


    for(int a=0;a<training.numAttributes()-1;a++)
    {
        if(training.attribute(a).isString())
        {
            nominal = new StringToNominal();
            nominal.setInputFormat(filteredInstaces);
            training = Filter.useFilter(training, nominal);
        }
    }

        tree.buildClassifier(filteredInstaces);

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testing);

        eval.evaluateModel(tree, testing);
        System.out.println("Precision:" + eval.precision(1));
        System.out.println("Recall:" + eval.recall(1));
        System.out.println("Fmeasure:" + eval.fMeasure(1));
        System.out.println("Error:" + eval.errorRate());

        precision += eval.precision(1);
        recall += eval.recall(1);
        fmeasure += eval.fMeasure(1);
        error += eval.errorRate();

        //update 
        begin = end + 1;
        end+= size1;

        if(i==(9))
        {
            end = dataset1.numInstances();
        }

        System.out.println("Precision:" + precision/10.0);
        System.out.println("Recall:" + recall/10.0);
        System.out.println("Fmeasure:" + fmeasure/10.0);
        System.out.println("Error:" + error/0.0);
    }


   // Classifier cls = new NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable();
// cls.buildClassifier(dataset1);
 // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
// Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset1);
 //eval.evaluateModel(cls, dataset2);
 //eval.crossValidateModel(cls,dataset1,10, dataset2.getRandomNumberGenerator(1));   
 //System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));

      } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm providing some tweets in C:\\1\data.txt. some tweets are as follow: wake nap negtoken taking.
taking nap reward.
bank card ruler money poor
alarm morning degree! single morning. engine
late nights early mornings.
bad 2am negtoken late anymore?

Answer (score 0):

The Naive Bayes classifiers in Weka won't accept string attributes, you'll need to convert the string attributes to nominal to start with. Weka has a filter for this purpose, StringToNominal, it should work assuming that all of the possible string values are represented in your first dataset (training set).

Comment: I've updaed the code with StringRONominal but still getting same error.. Please suggest a chnage or give me any reference example..

Comment: If you're getting the same error, there must be string attributes still present when you apply the classifier. Try catching exceptions when you apply the filter, you need more information.